# javascript parent question

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, parent

If I have a page with an iframe on it, then there is another iframe in that iframe, do I have to use parent.parent to reach the top frame or is there a shortcut to the page "root" that would be equivalent to parent.parent; or parent.parent.parent for that matter.. you get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.

```
window.top
```